# How to read multiple .mat file from a folder in python?

Tags: python, matlab, h5py

I am trying to read multiple .mat files in python. Every time I get the error. This is my code:

```
folder = "C:/Users/Sreeraj/Desktop/Me/PhD/Mahindra/brain_tumor_dataset/data/"
directs = sorted(listdir(folder))
labels = []
for file in directs:
    f = h5py.File(folder+file,'r')
    label = np.array(f.get("cjdata/label"))[0][0]
    labels.append(label)
labels = pd.Series(labels)
labels.shape
```

The error I am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e7d73f54f73d> in <module>
      3 labels = []
      4 for file in directs:
----> 5     f = h5py.File(folder+file,'r')
      6     label = np.array(f.get("cjdata/label"))[0][0]
      7     labels.append(label)

~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, track_order, **kwds)
    404             with phil:
    405                 fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, **kwds)
--> 406                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size,
    407                                fapl, fcpl=make_fcpl(track_order=track_order),
    408                                swmr=swmr)

~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    171         if swmr and swmr_support:
    172             flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
--> 173         fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
    174     elif mode == 'r+':
    175         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

I have 5849 mat files. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

I used h5py to read mat files. I wanted to read the labels and images in each .mat files.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is in concatenating `folder+file`.
2 things about that:

1. The word `file` is a python keyword, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name.
2. Assuming you used `os.listdir` here (you didn't attach the import itself), your concatenation of folder and file is missing a slash.
   [image]

A fix for that (after I renamed `file` to `filename`):

```py
full_file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
f = h5py.File(full_file_path,'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

I here are 4 areas where the code could be improved:

1. I prefer `glob.iglob()` method to get a list of files. It can use a
   wildcard to define the filenames, and is a generator. That way you don't
   have to create a list with 5849 mat filenames.
2. You open the file with `h5py.File()`, but don't close it. That
   probably won't cause a problem, but is bad practice. It's better to use
   Python's `with/as:` context manager. (If you don't do that, add `f.close()` inside the loop).
3. You are using the dataset `.get()` method to retrieve the dataset object. That method has been deprecated for quite some time. Documented practice is to reference the dataset name like this `f["cjdata/label"]`
4. Also, you added `[0][0]` after the dataset object. Are you sure you
   want to do that? They are indices that will access the dataset value at index=`[0][0]`. If you want to create a numpy array of the dataset values, use label = f["cjdata/label"][()]

Modified code that demonstrates all of these changes below:

```
folder = "C:/Users/Sreeraj/Desktop/Me/PhD/Mahindra/brain_tumor_dataset/data/"
file_wc = folder + "*.mat"  # assumes filename extension is .mat
labels = []
for fname in glob.iglob(file_wc):
    with h5py.File(fname,'r') as f:
        # dataset .get() method deprecated, line below updated appropriately:
        label = np.array(f["cjdata/label"][0][0])
        #or maybe just:
        label = f["cjdata/label"][()]
        labels.append(label)
labels = pd.Series(labels)
labels.shape
```